# How to add border to textbox in editable combobox?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have an editable combo box in wpf-mvvm application.

I would like to add a border to textbox in editable combobox. (This border will be in red..if user type some invalid entries in combobox.)

Please help.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path = ContractNumberList }" Width="90" IsEditable="True" SelectedItem="{Binding Path = ContractNumber,Mode=TwoWay}"
Text="{Binding Path = ContractNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
</ComboBox>
```

**EDIT** :
What I need is to override my editable combo-box's item template. I know that an editable combobox will have two items in it => textbox and a list. I need to add a border to this textbox .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Validation Rules

Here is the couple of links
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfvalidation.aspx
http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataValidation.html

Comment: I have my validation rules..But I need to display red color outside by combo-textbox ..when the entered data is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ValidationRules for this but I think it'll be pretty tricky since you would have to pass ContractNumberList to it in order to check for validity. An easier way is to make the ViewModel implement `IDataErrorInfo`, set `ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"` for the `Text` Binding and then do the validity check from your ViewModel. It can look similar to this

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContractNumberList}"
          Width="90"
          IsEditable="True"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ContractNumber,
                                 Mode=TwoWay}"
          Text="{Binding Path=ContractNumber,
                         UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,
                         ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
```

**View Model**

```
public class YourViewModel : IDataErrorInfo
{
    // ...
    public string ContractNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    // etc.

    #region IDataErrorInfo Members

    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string returnValue = string.Empty;
            if (columnName == "ContractNumber")
            {
                if (ContractNumberList.IndexOf(ContractNumber) < 0)
                {
                    returnValue = "Invalid selection";
                }
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: @Anish Mohan: This solution will place a red border around the TextBox when entering a value that isn't in the list. Are you sure you still want a templating solution?